# Analysing event rate in a computer system for alerting

Tags: frequency

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm to identify how frequently specific events occur on a computer system, so that I can categorise them based upon their rarity.

I can't keep a log of every event as there are too many, so I need a single record of each event and a numerical indicator for its 'Events per day/hour' etc. Let's say my threshold for notifications is 2 per day.

If EventA first occurs 10 days ago (and I record that) and then doesn't occur again until today, I'll update it's 'occurrences' count to 2, and  I can calculate that it occurs 'on average' once every 5 days. If it then occurs 8 times more over the next hour, my algorithm will record 10 occurrences over 10 days which is 1/day, but the most useful rate is actually 8/hour which I want to be alerted for.

Is there an algorithm for this? Should I discard any events that haven't occurred for my threshold period ? i.e. if I want to know about x occurrances of a specific event per day, and that event hasn't occurred for an day, should I discard the record of it?

Comment: this question can't be answered because we don't know what's best for you. you know

Comment: OK- let me see if I can edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Maybe look into [Control charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_chart). Add the tag [tag:control-chart] if that sounds right, and search this site.